# using regex for text matching a string

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file like:-

```
car - superb
company - skoda simply clever
manufactured - 1990
car - sclass
company - mercedes the best or nothing
manufactured - 1990    
car - rapid 
company - skoda simply clever
manufactured - 1990
```

If user raw_inputs the company name'skoda',then it must provide me 2 details,since the above text file has got 2 cars:-

```
superb
skoda simply clever
1990
rapid
skoda simply clever
1990
```

How can i use regex for the above problem, i have searched the entire 'SO',but didnot get matching my problem.Please help me with a solution!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show us some example code you have tried using a regex with?

Comment: I think you should change the text to a list of data, then compare user input  with each list item.

Comment: All pieces of your problem have already been answered on StackOverflow.

Comment: If you have text file like that then can't you use other methods (hint: `split()`) other than regex ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
car\s+-(?:(?!\bcar\b)[\s\S])*skoda(?:(?!\bcar\b)[\s\S])*
```

You can use this.This will give the section what you want.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/pT4tM5/14

```
x="""car - superb
company - skoda simply clever
manufactured - 1990
car - sclass
company - mercedes the best or nothing
manufactured - 1990
car - rapid
company - skoda simply clever
manufactured - 1990"""
temp="skoda"
print re.findall(r"car\s+-(?:(?!\bcar\b)[\s\S])*"+temp+r"(?:(?!\bcar\b)[\s\S])*",x)
```

Comment: can i use it even for a large text file?

Comment: @itadsd depends on how long your file is....give it a try though!!!!!!!